# Maintain right alignment in tabular with footnote

Tags: tables

In the following example, the presence of the footnote screws up the right alignment.  In other words, I'd like the numbers to be aligned and the footnote to jut out (possibly into the next column).  So I want the 4 to be ligned up with the 8 underneath it.  What is the easiest way to accomplish this, other than via a series of `\phantom`s and such?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lr}
ho & 3.14\footnotemark\\
hum & 22.78
\end{tabular}
\footnotetext{This is $\mathrm{\pi}$.} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How about: `hum & 22.78\phantom{\footnotemark\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}} \\` ?

Comment: Or `ho & 3.14\rlap{\footnotemark}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, an `\rlap` of the `\footnotemark` will work, because the footnote takes place in the right-most column.  Elsewise, the `\footnotemark` will encroach on the intercolumn gap and Christian's suggestion might be better.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lr}
ho & 3.14\rlap{\footnotemark}\\
hum & 22.78
\end{tabular}
\footnotetext{This is $\mathrm{\pi}$.} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I can work with the encroachment, but don't want to phantom all other elements in the column.

Comment: @JPi If the encroachment became an issue between columns, one could manually enlarge that column gapping during the invocation: `\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{\dimexpr2\tabcolsep+3pt}}r}`

Answer (score 2):

with use of `siunitx` package is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=2.2,
                   table-space-text-post=\footnotemark
                   ]}
ho & 3.14\footnotemark\\
hum & 22.78
\end{tabular}
\footnotetext{This is $\mathrm{\pi}$.}

\end{document}
```

[image]